# Access Firebase access token through Firebase Admin PHP SDK

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have generated myself a service account with .json file for Firebase Admin PHP SDK authorization.

Aside from that, I would want to use the same service account for authenticating Clodfunctions API calls, without the need for authorizing another service account and getting token for it (that'll be used in API calls).

Is there a way to extract the access token from Factory object I initialized with my service account .json file?

More on Factory initialization is explained [here](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html#google-service-account). I went through source code but none of the methods exist that would give me this option. Some of them could potentially store this data, but they are all private; used only inside core classes used for communication with Firebase database.

Answer (score 1):

With version 6.x of the SDK, you can use the `Factory::createApiClient()` method to create an API client that you should be able to use for custom calls to the Firebase APIs.

https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/dba320d74f6529dab8fe33978b9a37fa83286e35/src/Firebase/Factory.php#L587

As an alternative, you can directly use the [`google/auth`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php) library and use the same Service Account to create your own API client.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know there was a method that creates a HTTP client. I tried this but I get 403 Forbidden response. I'm not sure if there is a problem with permissions on endpoints, or if that's a response that you can get with wrongly authenticated request. Is there a way for me to debug this? I know that cloudfunctions expect a Bearer token, but it's not added in this client, I don't know if cloudfunctions know how to authenticate these requests in the way SDK is authenticating these calls.